# Appending Objects to Commands

Tags: objetos-indirectos, objetos-directos

My question regards the usage objects with commands. I said to my girlfriend, a native speaker “Pásalela” with my meaning being “Pass her (the waitress) the bill.”

She said this does not sound right to her. She thought I should say Pásalo. Are feminine nouns denoted with the neuter object lo? Is the indirect object superfluous or incorrect?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

Lo más correcto desde mi punto de vista sería decir;

Pásasela (la cuenta) a la camarera, o si se sobrentiende por el contexto como es el caso simplemente "Pásasela" (la cuenta a ella).

También puedes decir "pásala" (la cuenta), sin embargo al no utilizar el pronombre reflexivo quien recibe la acción queda indeterminado.

Si se dice solo "pásalo" el objeto y la acción aún quedan más indeterminadas y puede dar lugar a mal entendidos o confusiones.

El pronombre reflexivo "se" normalmente aparece en frases en que el sujeto y el complemento directo o el complemento indirecto son la misma persona".

Otros ejemplos;

- Si ya no vas a utilizar tu cuenta, pásase**la** a tu hij**a**.
- Si ya no vas a utilizar tu cuenta, pásase**lo** a tu hij**o**.
- Pásaselo a tu tío, me dijo que le guardara el artículo.

**P.D.**
Como muy amablemente me ha sugerido @tchrist por si querría mencionar la regla siguiente:

> «El objeto indirecto "le / les" pasa a ser el "se" al seguirle un objeto
> directo (OD) de segunda persona formal o de tercera persona; es si le
> sigue uno de los siguientes pronombres (lo, los, la, las) el OI se
> combina con el OD en las combinaciones indivisibles "se lo", "se los", "se
> la", "se las", procedentes de las formas medievales "gelo", "gelos", "gela",
> "gelas"»

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemento_indirecto

Muchas gracias @tchrist

Comment: Tal vez querrás mencionar la regla: «[El objeto indirecto *le / les* pasa a ser el *se* al seguirle un objeto directo (OD) de segunda persona formal o de tercera persona; es si le sigue uno de los siguientes pronombres (*lo, los, la, las*) el OI se combina con el OD en las combinaciones indivisibles *se lo, se los, se la, se las*, procedentes de las formas medievales *gelo, gelos, gela, gelas*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemento_indirecto)»

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario, estoy de acuerdo contigo, lo añadiré y te daré las gracias, si no te importa. Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: These explanations are right but complicated for a learner.